# Terraform error when calling value index from a map index in list

Tags: terraform

I have a variable of map type which has index value of instance type. Right now I am using single aws single instance class in the index :-

```
default = {
"0" = "r4.2xlarge"
"1" = "m4.large"
"2" = "r4.4xlarge"
"3" = "m3.xlarge"  
"4" = "m3.xlarge"  
"5" = "m4.xlarge"
"6" = "m4.xlarge"
"7" = "c4.xlarge"  
"8" = "m4.large"
"9" = "m4.large" }
```

My terraform call the index like the one below :-

```
instance_types {
spot     = ["${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}"]
```

}

What I am trying to add multiple instance class in the map as a list, like this :-

```
default = {
"0" = ["r4.2xlarge","r4.xlarge"]
"1" = ["m4.large","m4.xlarge"]
"2" = ["r4.4xlarge","r4.xlarge"]
"3" = ["m3.xlarge","m4.xlarge"]  
"4" = ["m3.xlarge","m4.xlarge"]  
"5" = ["m4.xlarge","m4.large"]
"6" = ["m4.xlarge","m4.large"]
"7" = ["c4.xlarge","c4.large"]  
"8" = ["m4.large","m4.xlarge"]
"9" = ["m4.large","m4.xlarge"] }
```

Terraform apply throws below error :

Error: spotinst_aws_group.private_servers: 10 error(s) occurred:

- spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[3]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[7]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[2]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[0]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[8]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[1]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[6]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[9]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[5]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[4]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in:

${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}

Is there a way this can be done or is it even possible? So far couldn't get the answer from anyone.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to actually achieve here. Can you state more precisely what you want to do and then show how what you've tried doesn't work?

Comment: I am using spotinst provider to provision spot machines on AWS. In this solution I provision a full integrated environment using terraform. This helps provision 10 machine of different class in one go. For the full terraform file please see :- https://github.com/rajdeepbhattacharya/terraform/blob/master/sample.tf . I know that we can give one instance class in terraform like , but I want to give 2 type of instance class in form of a list.

Comment: I can't really understand why you're creating 10 spot instances with different AMIs and instance types at the same time. Are they meant to be performing the same work and you have a very peculiarly heterogeneous mix for this? Or are they all doing different things? If they are doing different things why are you creating them all at the same time instead of individually and reducing the complexity of your code?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: These are 10 functionally different application golden images, so that why 10 different image id's. The memory and core requirement of these application is different that why we have different instance class. We want the intergrated environment to spinned up in one go (that saves us lot of time :) ) that's why we have designed it in that way.

Comment: I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the best place to discuss this but your approach seems overly complicated to me instead of just defining 10 separate spot inst groups considering they are all doing different things. That said I can't see what is actually functionally wrong with what you're trying, Terraform should return the list that maps to the index.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR there is no problem with the single instance class in the map index. But when using 2 instance classes in the map index the issue occurs.

Comment: What issue? You haven't shown an error or explained some unusual behaviour at all.

Comment: Error: spotinst_aws_group.private_servers: 10 error(s) occurred:
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[3]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in: ${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
* spotinst_aws_group.private_servers[7]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in: ${lookup(var.spot_instance_types, count.index)}
This should make it clear

Comment: You should edit the error into your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing @ydaetskcoR. I have added the error message.